# How to use ':' in JPA native query?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am doing some data analysis and I have a SQL query that uses `SELECT ..., @rownum:=@rownum+1 as row_number, ...` to get the row number along with the results. However when I put this into a native query on my JPA method (using Spring Boot / Spring Data JPA), I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'
```

I have added `@Query(nativeQuery = true,` to my method, and have changed my parameters from things like `where first_name = :firstname` to `where first_name = ?1` and removed the `@Param` annotation from my method parameters, but it hasn't helped.

Is there a way to escape the colon in this query, or some other way of assigning the rownum variable that doesn't use a colon?

Comment: try to use `"SELECT ..., @rownum\\:=@rownum+1 as row_number, ... "`

Comment: Doh the JPA stacktrace was so huge it didn't even occur to me to try the simplest of Java escaping, that fixed it thanks! If you make it an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve this issue you need to escape the two dots with double backslash `\\:`

```
"SELECT ..., @rownum\\:=@rownum+1 as row_number, ... "
                    ^^^
```

Comment: @menoktaokan Have you find the solution?

Comment: @SaranshDhyani I crated a trigger on the DB and used it.

Comment: Does not work in all scenarios with hibernate 5.6.15, as hibernate will sill run processFilters even for native queries and throw an IllegalArgumentException for e.g. array offsets in postgresql